# Beamer: how to make each frame appear in the PDF toc?

Tags: beamer, pdf

I would like to have a beamer presentation in which *every* frame appears in the PDF table of contents (i.e. has a bookmark). My specific presentation only has sections, so all of the frames can appear as a "subsection" on the PDF. Note that I don't want to make a subsection for each frame.

One way to do that is make up a command that patches frametitle by calling the appropriate bookmark command of hyperref. Is there any better way?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want them to show up on the frame containing the table of contents or do you want to see them in your PDF viewer's sidebar/listing?

Comment: I want them to show up only on the PDF viewer's sidebar.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a solution that patches an auxiliary macro in `\frametitle`, adding code that adds a bookmark and table-of-contents line as if it were a subsection (you can just comment this out if not wanted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection{\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% save the current definition of \beamer@@frametitle
\let\nobookmarkbeamer@@frametitle\beamer@@frametitle
% then patch it to do the bookmarks and/or TOC entries
\apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{%
  % keep this to add the frame title to the TOC at the "subsection level"
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@subsectionintoc{\the\c@section}{0}{#1}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}%
        {\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}%
  % keep this line to add a bookmark that shows up in the PDF TOC at the subsection level
  \bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1}%
  }%
  {\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle succeeded **}}%
  {\errmessage{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle failed **}}%

\pretocmd{\beamer@checknoslide}{%
  % ensure the bookmark is not created if the slide is filtered out
  \let\beamer@@frametitle\nobookmarkbeamer@@frametitle
  }%
  {\message{** patching of \string\beamer@checknoslide succeeded **}}%
  {\errmessage{** patching of \string\beamer@checknoslide failed **}}%

\makeatother



\begin{document}



\section{First Section}

\begin{frame}{First frame}Text\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second frame}Text\end{frame}



\section{Second Section}

\begin{frame}{Third frame}Text\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Fourth frame}Text\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<handout>\frametitle{Fifth frame}Text\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

I had to dig around in `beamerbasesection.sty` to figure that out.  But it seems to work.

[image: Output]

**EDIT.** (by cyberSingularity): Now prevents unwanted bookmarks when the slide is not shown by also patching `\beamer@checknoslide`, and provided an additional frame to test.

Note: if there are frames with multiple slides (e.g. due to `\pause`s), you may also be interested in [this follow up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66519).

Comment: @cyberSingularity: Very useful addon, thanks for sharing it!

Comment: Am I the only one to have issues with this patch when printing the bibliography? `ERROR: Missing } inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                }
l.6 \beamer@sectionintoc {1}`and my first section

Comment: This adds duplicate entries to TOC when a single slide uses \framebreak