# Make each frame (not slide) appear in the PDF bookmarks with beamer

Tags: beamer, bookmarks

I have written a `beamer` presentation and I would like all the frames to have corresponding PDF bookmarks, much like as in this other question on here: [Beamer: how to make each frame appear in the PDF toc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17230) . However, it seems that the answer given to that question makes every *slide* get a bookmark, so frames with `\pause`s which have multiple corresponding slides get duplicate bookmarks.

(My understanding is that in `beamer`, a `frame` is the logical concept defined as everything between the `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}` and may be represented in the output as one or more `slide`s.)

I include a minimum illustrative example, based on the previously referenced answer, which I compile with `pdflatex` (and my `\beamer@version`=`3.20`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1}}%
{\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle succeeded **}}%
{\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle failed **}}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
Hello \pause world
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result: a PDF with one frame but two slides, and *two* bookmarks, one for each *slide*.
Wanted: a PDF with one frame but two slides, and *one* bookmark, one for each *frame*.

I am surprised that the example doesn't work, as I would have thought that `\frametitle` (or rather its `\@dblarg` helper `\beamer@@frametitle`) would get called once per frame instead of (as it appears given the result) once per slide. (Is there any implementation documentation for beamer that might help me with this, as so far I've failed to find it?)

Also, as my presentation is already written, I would like to avoid having to replace `\begin{frame}` with `\begin{myframe}` everywhere if possible (especially as some of my frames use the `\frametitle{Title}` syntax and others the `\begin{frame}{Title}` syntax of setting the frame title), and I'm aware that there will be a few difficulties in this approach.

Comment: To answer the part about why this didn't do what I expected, it seems beamer processes the frame body multiple times when there are pauses and/or overlays, and `\frametitle` is part of the frame body (using either syntax).

Comment: Note to users: the [answer to the original question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17233) has been extended with an extra patch for handling cases with mode specifications better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{\only<1>{\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1}}}%
{\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle succeeded **}}%
{\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle failed **}}%
\makeatother
```

adds the bookmark just for the first slide in each frame (or at least it seems to work on your MWE)

Comment: That does indeed work, thanks, and is (embarrassingly) much simpler than anything I was going to think of. This has also led me to the idea of having one bookmark per slide, but with the 'slide in frame' number part of the bookmark caption: replacing the `\apptocmd` line with `\apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1 (\the\beamer@slideinframe)}}%` achieves that. Hope this helps someone else too. (And it seems I can put off learning more about beamer's implementation a little longer...)

Comment: why if I put these lines of code into a `.sty` file it does not work?

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me; I get the following error message: `Undefined control sequence. \beamer@doifinframe ->\bookmark   [page=\the \c@page ,level=3]`

Comment: @xFioraMstr18 the code here still works, you show `\bookmark` undefined which indicates you have not loaded `bookmark` package

Comment: Okay, your answer works now when I `\usepackage{bookmark}`

Comment: Incidentally, why do you put empty comments `%` after each of your middle three lines?

Comment: @xFioraMstr18 I copied the style in the question, not needed here but https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat

Answer (score 1):

I am so happy to find this and the related thread. This is my final working solution. And I take no credit for this. I am just posting hear for some rookie Latex user like me to figure out easier:

```
  \AtBeginSection{\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}}

  \usepackage{bookmark}
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \makeatletter
  % save the current definition of \beamer@@frametitle
  \let\nobookmarkbeamer@@frametitle\beamer@@frametitle
  % then patch it to do the bookmarks and/or TOC entries
  % \apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{%
  \apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{%
  \only<1>{\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1}}
  }%
  {\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle succeeded **}}%
  {\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle failed **}}%

  \pretocmd{\beamer@checknoslide}{%
    % ensure the bookmark is not created if the slide is filtered out
    \let\beamer@@frametitle\nobookmarkbeamer@@frametitle
    }%
    {\message{** patching of \string\beamer@checknoslide succeeded **}}%
    {\errmessage{** patching of \string\beamer@checknoslide failed **}}%

  \makeatother
```

And for those who use markdown pandoc:

````
header-includes: |
  ```{=latex}
  % add bookmark level 2 for PDF
  % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17230/beamer-how-to-make-each-frame-appear-in-the-pdf-toc

  \AtBeginSection{\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}}

  \usepackage{bookmark}
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \makeatletter
  % save the current definition of \beamer@@frametitle
  \let\nobookmarkbeamer@@frametitle\beamer@@frametitle
  % then patch it to do the bookmarks and/or TOC entries
  % \apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{%
  \apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{%
  \only<1>{\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1}}
  }%
  {\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle succeeded **}}%
  {\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle failed **}}%

  \pretocmd{\beamer@checknoslide}{%
    % ensure the bookmark is not created if the slide is filtered out
    \let\beamer@@frametitle\nobookmarkbeamer@@frametitle
    }%
    {\message{** patching of \string\beamer@checknoslide succeeded **}}%
    {\errmessage{** patching of \string\beamer@checknoslide failed **}}%

  \makeatother
  ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant of David Carlisle's answer obtained by using `\pdfbookmark` in place of `\bookmark`. The advantage here is that we do not need to `\usepackage{bookmark}`.

```
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{\only<1>{\pdfbookmark[3]{#1}{#1}}}
{\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle succeeded **}}
{\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle failed **}}
\makeatother
```