# Memoir - Feature request - custom spacing for quote environments

Tags: spacing, memoir, thesis

I am in he process of writing a dissertation with memoir. This is the third time I use memoir for my research production and it really preserved my sanity.

Now, due to the very peculiar rules of the institution where I am studying for my degree, I must format my dissertation with double space. However, block quotes (meaning, `quote` and `quotation` environments) must be typesed single-spaced. Currently, there is no parameter in memoir to typeset text in this way that I'm aware of.

Thankfully, searching this site, I've found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118360/applying-custom-size-and-spacing-to-quote-environment) which was really helpful, and I was able to achieve what I wanted with minimum modifications.

But I would like to suggest, if possible and as a feature request, that memoir could have a way to configure this parameter. Perhaps a double-starred version for the spacing commands (such as `\DoubleSpacing`) or a starred version of the blockquote environments (`quote` and `quotation`) could do this.

Thanks are due to Peter Wilson, Lars Madsen and the cast of thousands who helped with memoir in any way or another.

So, is it possible to add a way to have a single-spaced blockquote environment within double or one-half spaced body text in memoir...?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Feature requests are off-topic to this site. They should be directed straight at the maintainer of the package(s) in question.

Comment: Note that `quote` and `quotation` are simply single item lists, that automatically added the starting `\item`. Thus making custom quote envs based on lists made with `enumitem` would be the way I'd go.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks.As for your observation, I also thought that, but Lars Madsen, memoir maintaner, stated on p xxxiii of the memoir manual the following: " Therefore it is probably safer to ask questions, complain, *make suggestions*, etc., on a Q&A site
like http://tex.stackexchange.com, which is archived and read by many, than correspond directly with the maintainer, who might well be away for some considerable time and perhaps not notice your email after having returned to base" (version v3.7r, 2022/07/29).

That's why I went here. The memoir maintainer requested it...

Comment: daleif: I already solved the issue for me based on the question linked. What I wanted is to request a feature, "make a suggestion" as the memoir maintanier would say.

Comment: The maintainer suggested not "requested" it. The maintainer has no influence over what TeX.SE supports or otherwise. --- GOM