# Using \filename@parse gives error

Tags: parsing

I am trying to use the `\filename@parse` like this:

```
\filename@parse{\lstname}
```

but I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.22 \filename
              @parse{\lstname}
?
```

Am I missing some package?

Comment: See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106174/makeatletter-explained

Comment: I added \makeatletter and it got past this point. It does now complain about \lstname, but that is a different question.

Comment: On that basis, I'll close this one as a dupe