# Font selection using key=val in custom article class

Tags: macros, document-classes, class-options, kvoptions

I am writing a simple class based on `article` that loads some commonly used packages and sets some defaults. The document font should be a `key=value` option `\documentclass{myarticle}`. For example, `font=charter`, `font=utopia` and `font=libertine` set the font to Charter, Utopia and Linux Libertine, respectively. Charter should be the default (just passing `font` should not be possible). I am having trouble setting this up using the `kvoptions` package. If I understand correctly I should use `\DeclareStringOption[charter]{font}[]` to set `charter` as the default of no `font=` is specified, but I am not sure where to declare the other options. In the documentation I see the function `\SetupKeyvalOptions{}`, but I don't understand what `familiy`, `prefix` and `setkeys` mean. The documentation is not clear on this (at least not to someone who's never done this kind of thing before).

I figured I would put the lines required to set the font in some kind of `if` `else` statement. I have looked at the `ifthen` package but I don't understand how to combine that with `kvoptions`. Also, it seems `ifthen` requires nesting of the different statements (correct?), which quickly becomes messy since I have more font options.

Here is what I have now for `myarticle.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myarticle}[2020/07/28 Custom article class]
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

\SetupKeyvalOptions{
    family = font,
    prefix = font@
}

\DeclareStringOption[charter]{font}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\iffont@charter
    \RequirePackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\else\iffont@utopia
    \RequirePackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}
\else
    \RequirePackage{libertine,libertinust1math}
\fi
```

and `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[font=utopia]{myarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    Content...
\end{document}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to evaluate the option in the if statement. Can you only evaluate true/false statements?

PS. I am also a little confused by the `\iffam` command I see [here](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94wright-keyval.pdf) (page 112). How does the combination between `\if` and `fam` work?

**EDIT**:

I have changed `myarticle.cls` to:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myarticle}[2020/07/28 Custom article class]
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\SetupKeyvalOptions{family = opt, prefix = opt@}

\DeclareStringOption[charter]{font}

\ifdefstring{\opt@font}{charter}{\RequirePackage[charter]{mathdesign}}{}
\ifdefstring{\opt@font}{utopia}{\RequirePackage[utopia]{mathdesign}}{}
\ifdefstring{\opt@font}{libertine}{\RequirePackage{libertine,libertinust1math}}{}
\ifdefstring{\opt@font}{lmodern}{\RequirePackage{lmodern}}{}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions{opt}
```

Changing the default in `\DeclareStringOption` now changes the document font, but setting another option in `\documentclass` has no effect.

**EDIT2**:
Moving `\ProcessKeyvalOptions{opt}` to directly below `\DeclareStringOption[charter]{font}` solves my problem. Still, I'd like to know if this is a "good" approach to doing this.

Comment: The options you define with `\DeclareStringOption` et al. are only processed at the point you call `\ProcessKeyvalOptions`. Before that you can not rely on any code these options execute or any macros/strings they define. Since `\DeclareStringOption[charter]{font}` just sets `\opt@font`, you can only use `\opt@font` after `\ProcessKeyvalOptions` if you want to actually grab the class options. In your case that means moving `\ProcessKeyvalOptions{opt}` to before the `\ifdefstring{\opt@font}` block.

Comment: Note that `family = opt, prefix = opt@` are fairly generic and may thus clash with other packages/classes. Maybe choose a more unique name like `family = avsopt, prefix = avsopt@`

Comment: About `\iffam`: `\iffam@active` is a single command, with `@` in its command name. The same holds for `\iffam@final`. Related: [\makeatletter explained](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106174/).