# Defining Polymorphic objects in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

I'm currently writing my masters thesis and I'm using algorithm2e to write pseudocode. I regularly use `SetKwData` to display data types. However I would slighty like to change how this is displayed when using arguments.

If I for example would like to display a key value map data type that is polymorphic in both the key, and data I would write something like this

```
\SetKwData{DFoo}{Foo}
\SetKwData{DBar}{Bar}
\SetKwData{DMap}{Map}

\Dmap{\DFoo, DBar}
```

Then the compiled document would look something like

```
Map(Foo, Bar)
```

In my opinion this looks too much like a function call. I would like to change the parenthesis to something like `Map<Foo, Bar>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example below, based on how `\SetKwData{Kw}{the text}` is defined in `algorithm2e.sty`, a generalized macro `\SetKwMetaData{Kw}{the text}{left delimiter}{right delimiter}` is provided, which allows you to specify the delimiters. These delimiters were hard coded to be `(` and `)` in `\SetKwData`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
% \SetKwMetaData{Kw}{the text}{left delimiter}{right delimiter}
\newcommand{\SetKwMetaData}[4]{%
  \algocf@newcommand{@#1}[1]{\DataSty{#2#3}\ArgSty{##1}\DataSty{#4}}%
  \algocf@newcommand{#1}{%
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\csname @#1\endcsname}{\DataSty{#2}\xspace}}%
  }%
\makeatother

\SetKwData{DFoo}{Foo}
\SetKwData{DBar}{Bar}
\SetKwMetaData{DMap}{Map}{$\langle$}{$\rangle$}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \DFoo{a}\\
  \DMap{\DFoo, \DBar}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i tried something similar but without the `\makeatletter`, and `\makeatother`. Not sure why they are required but it works! thank you

Comment: This pair of macros change and restore the catcode of `@` character, so `@` can be used as part of the name of control sequence, directly and locally (for example in `\algocf@newcommand`). Find more explanation in, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106174/makeatletter-explained .