# Frame titles for PDF chapters in Beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, pdf

Pardon me if this question has been duplicated elsewhere, I'm still coming to terms with tex terminology.

I am generating a presentation in Beamer. I like the use of PDF chapters to navigate between slides as well. I use sections to break up the presentation into... sections. However, the ideal subsection heading is just the frametitle. Is there any way to automate the process of retroactively creating subsections based on input to `\frametitle`?

My document is set up a bit like the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Research essentials}
Researchers are responsible for many aspects of study design and protocols
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overview}
In this presentation we will be talking about Review Boards, Funding Mechanisms, Statistical Analysis Plans, and Manuscripts
\end{frame}    

\section{IRBs}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Institutional Review Boards}
IRBs independently review study applications to ensure that the degree of invasiveness is justified, the results of scientific interest, and the confidentiality of study participants protected
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like the PDF chapters left hand bar on Adobe to show the following breakdown

```
Introduction
- Research Essentials
- Overview
IRBs
- Institutional Review Boards
```

Comment: Probably the theme you are using has a navigation bar on the top or on the lateral.

Comment: I could compile for two different themes, but I plan to: 1. Plug it into a projector for visual aide, 2. Print off handouts, and 3. Share electronic copies. Having PDF chapters conveniently fits all 3 into one "theme" (which relies on the PDF viewer to list sections).

Comment: You may try http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66519/make-each-frame-not-slide-appear-in-the-pdf-bookmarks-with-beamer

Comment: @knut thank you that solved my problem exactly. I'd vote to close my own post as an identical copy of the one you linked, but apparently one can only do that if they are *not* the poster. Shall I delete the question?

Comment: I flagged it as a duplicate. I think it will be closed very fast ;)