# Beamer bookmarks with allowframbreaks

Tags: beamer, bookmarks

Consider the following MWE which uses this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66520/9953) to generate a bookmark for each frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{%
  \only<1>{\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1}}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Foo}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{Baz}
  \lipsum
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When `allowframebreaks` option is given this means that a bookmark is generated for each of the new frames created by the mentioned option. I want the bookmarks of these "continuation"  frames to either have the proper frametitle (i.e "Baz II" rather than just "Baz") or just to generate a bookmark for the first frame and not for those created by the `allowframebreak` option.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Insert countinuation count in bookmark**

The basic idea behind this approach is to check if the `\insertcontinuationcount` is greater than 0. In this case the continuation count is added to the bookmark.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{%
    \only<1>{\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1 \expandafter\ifnum\insertcontinuationcount>0\relax\insertcontinuationcount\fi}}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Foo}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{Baz}
        \lipsum
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Only bookmarks for first frame**

This approach is very similar to the one above. But now, a bookmark is only added if the `\insertcontinuationcount` is smaller than 2, because it is 0 for "normal" frames or 1 for the first frame of a continuation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{%
    \only<1>{\expandafter\ifnum\insertcontinuationcount<2\relax\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1}\fi}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Foo}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{Baz}
        \lipsum
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thank! Do you know how to achieve the other possibility of avoiding bookmarks for "continuation frames"?

Comment: Also when there are no continuation frames is it possible to avoid numbering it as `Foo 0`? And just name the bookmark as `Foo`.

Comment: @petobens: see my edited answer to adress your two questions

Comment: @petobens: does this solve your problem?

Comment: I've recently noticed two minor problems with your solution: i) if a give the `allowframebreaks` options but the resulting frame has no continuation frames then the bookmark for that frame still shows `Foo I` rather than just `Foo` ii) if I use the option `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][\insertcontinuationcountroman]` the first frame in the bookmarks shows `Foo I` whereas in the text it is actually `Foo` and then the second one `Foo II`. Do you want me to open a another question?

Comment: @petobens: concerning your first problem i) The same applies for the frametitle. I don't think this is easily solvable. Perhapse it would be best to open a new question

Comment: @petobens: concerning ii) If you would like the `Foo I` to be unnumbered, simply change the >0 to a >1.

Comment: Great changing to >1 fixes i) and ii)!!!