# Beamer: how to make each frame appear in the PDF ToC and add a bibliography

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, bibliographies, pdf

I want to build on the solution of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17233/27466), to create a ToC for the PDF, by adding a bibliography in the last slide. It seems nevertheless that the bibliography interferes with the table of contents, and TeX outputs the error

```
ERROR: Missing } inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                }
l.5 ...er@sectionintoc {1}{First Section}{1}{0}{1}
```

Please consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection{\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% save the current definition of \beamer@@frametitle
\let\nobookmarkbeamer@@frametitle\beamer@@frametitle
% then patch it to do the bookmarks and/or TOC entries
\apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{%
  % keep this to add the frame title to the TOC at the "subsection level"
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@subsectionintoc{\the\c@section}{0}{#1}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}%
    {\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}%
  % keep this line to add a bookmark that shows up in the PDF TOC at the subsection level
  \bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1}%
}%
{\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle succeeded **}}%
{\errmessage{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle failed **}}%

\pretocmd{\beamer@checknoslide}{%
  % ensure the bookmark is not created if the slide is filtered out
  \let\beamer@@frametitle\nobookmarkbeamer@@frametitle
}%
{\message{** patching of \string\beamer@checknoslide succeeded **}}%
{\errmessage{** patching of \string\beamer@checknoslide failed **}}%

\makeatother

% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[
backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
  @book{test1,
    address = {London},
    url = {www.jstor.com/somearticle.html},
    urldate = {2013-10-29},
    title = {Cyberprotest: {New} media, citizens, and social movements},
    publisher = {Routledge},
    editor = {van de Donk, Wim B. H. J.},
    year = {2004}
  }
  @misc{test2,
    title = {This is the title of the webpage},
    url = {www.blog.com},
    urldate = {2013-08-29},
    journal = {This is the title of the website},
    month = feb,
    year = {2009}
  }
}
\end{filecontents*}

  \addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\begin{frame}{First frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item item2
  \item item1

  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second frame}Text\end{frame}

\section{Second Section}

\begin{frame}{Third frame}Text\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\autocite{test1, test2}

  % \printbibliography % <- when uncommenting this line TeX return an error

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The code compiles for me. Therefore I don't see what's the question here.