# Add \paragraph type entries to beamer table of contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sections-paragraphs

I want a beamer TOC slide like this:

SECTION 1
..Subsection 1
......Slide Title 1
..Subsection 2
......Slide Title 2
......Slide Title 2
NEXT SECTION
......Another Slide Title

In documents I use \paragraph to get the next level in on the TOC, but it does not seem to be supported in beamer.  =(

It'd be best if the slidetitles get included in the TOC automatically (kind of like this: [Beamer: how to make each frame appear in the PDF toc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17230/beamer-how-to-make-each-frame-appear-in-the-pdf-toc/186864?noredirect=1#comment432486_186864) )  But I'd be OK with changing the \slidetitle command to also put in a \paragraph command.

Here is some (possibly orthogonal) working code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide 1}
This is some content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: I wonder if this'd be solved by using a different theme.

Comment: Why use `paragraph` instead of `subsubsection`? If you put a subsubsection before every frame you will get the result you want. Not a automatically way, but it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

The following answer opens a new `\subsubsection` at the beginning of every frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{
    \subsubsection{\insertframetitle}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    \section{Section 1}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Slide 1}
        This is some content
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Slide 2}
        This is some content
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is a crime nonetheless ;)