# Beamer: \framesubtitle without \frametitle

Tags: beamer, frame-title

It it possible to use `\framesubtitle` without `\frametitle` in `Beamer`?
Because, I want to use `\frametitle` for `sections` and `\framesubtitle` for `subsections`.

Comment: The title of your post and the body seem to be asking opposite things ...

Comment: @JosephWright Ahhhhhh. Good point. Didn't read the title well enough,

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Added more explanation.

Comment: @JosephWright Corrected.

Comment: Did you try it? Wouldn't that be a lot faster than asking here and waiting for an answer?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner But what's the question, then? Does the code give an error? If not, what?

Comment: _I want to use frame title for sections and frame subtitle for subsections._ -- Do you look for something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17230/beamer-how-to-make-each-frame-appear-in-the-pdf-toc or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66519/make-each-frame-not-slide-appear-in-the-pdf-bookmarks-with-beamer ?

Comment: :( @Dr.ManuelKuehner I wasn't suggesting you should do the OP's work ....

Comment: Add `{~}` like this: `\begin{frame}{~}
\framesubtitle{SubTittle}
Text.
\end{frame}`, does this seem right?

Comment: @AboAmmar But I dont want the belt created by `\frametitle{~}`.

Comment: @knut Not really (my problem is just showing subsection names in framesubtitle part without requiring to use frametitle) but thank you.

Comment: If I recall correctly, [tag:beamer] will typeset the subtitle only if the title is nonempty. In other words, you **have to** create that belt and then hide it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two approaches.

The first approach defines a magic word called `please hide this title`. Whenever the title is exactly this string, it will be hidden.

This definition of `frametitle` template is simply a copy of the original one in `beamerouterthemedefault.sty` line 149-169, except that the line generating the title is wrapped in a `\ifx`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\stringpleasehidethistitle{{please hide this title\ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount>0\relax{}\space\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}\fi}}
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{only sub}[1][left]
{
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,#1,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fte#1\endcsname\fi%
    \ifx\insertframetitle\stringpleasehidethistitle%   check if magic word presents
    \else%                                             check if magic word presents
      \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%               check if magic word presents
    \fi%                                               check if magic word presents
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\frame{{please hide this title}{only subtitle}}
\frame{{I want title}{title appears!}}
\frame{{please hide this title}{only subtitle again!}}
\frame{{I want title the second time}{title appears again!}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The second approach defines an alternative `frametitle` template which ironically shows no frametitle. This definition is simply a copy of the original one in `beamerouterthemedefault.sty` line 149-169, except that the line generating the title is commented out.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{only sub}[1][left]
{
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,#1,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fte#1\endcsname\fi%
    %\strut\insertframetitle\strut\par% <-- This line is commented out
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\frame{{this title will be ignored}{only subtitle}}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default]
\frame{{switch back to the default}{title appears!}}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[only sub]
\frame{{this title will be ignored again}{only subtitle again!}}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default]
\frame{{switch back to the default again}{title appears again!}}

\end{document}
```

The result is basically the same as before.